# GHCi can't resolve names in two versions of the same package

Tags: haskell, ghci, parsec

I'm trying to use Parsec's `OperatorTable` with the following:

```
table :: Ex.OperatorTable String () Identity Expr
table = [[]]
```

`cabal build` and `cabal run` work, but loading `Main` into GHCi gives me this weird error:

```
Parser.hs:127:33:
    Couldn't match type ‘Identity’
                  with ‘transformers-0.3.0.0:Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’
    NB: ‘Identity’
          is defined in ‘Data.Functor.Identity’
              in package ‘transformers-0.4.3.0’
        ‘transformers-0.3.0.0:Data.Functor.Identity.Identity’
          is defined in ‘Data.Functor.Identity’
              in package ‘transformers-0.3.0.0’
    Expected type: Ex.OperatorTable
                     String () transformers-0.3.0.0:Data.Functor.Identity.Identity Expr
      Actual type: Ex.OperatorTable String () Identity Expr
    In the first argument of ‘Ex.buildExpressionParser’, namely ‘table’
    In the expression: Ex.buildExpressionParser table factor
```

So I deleted `~/.cabal` and `.cabal-sandbox` and reinstalled `mtl`, both globally and in a new sandbox Same error.

`ghc-pkg list | grep trans` gives:

```
transformers-0.3.0.0
transformers-0.4.3.0
```

so I tried `ghc-pkg unregister transformers-0.3.0.0` but got a scary-looking warning message about how a bunch of other packages would break:

```
ghc-pkg: unregistering transformers-0.3.0.0 would break the following
packages: regex-posix-0.95.2 regex-compat-0.95.1 regex-base-0.93.2
parsec-3.1.5 network-2.4.2.3 mtl-2.1.3.1 fgl-5.5.0.1 HTTP-4000.2.10
ghc-7.8.3 haskeline-0.7.1.2 (use --force to override)
```

Didn't proceed.

Also tried `ghci -package transformers-0.4.3.0` and got the same error.

What do I do now? :\

My `.cabal` file contains `transformers <= 0.4.3.0`. I'm on GHC 7.8.3 on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: why don't you constraint it to `transformers < 0.4.3.0` or even to `0.3.0.0`?  It's hard to give you good advice if we don't see the "scary looking warning" - btw: did you start up ghci in your sandbox `cabal repl`?

Comment: Tried constraining it but didn't work also. I've edited the original post to include the warning. Starting with `cabal repl` worked but had some other problems, like not being able to see other modules in my project (trying to figure out why). I guess my question is: in general, how do I use newer versions of libraries and resolve such conflicts?

Comment: the problem is that normally you are not allowed have multiple versions of the same lib installed - you can in a sandbox but then you should tell GHCi to look there (`cabal repl` basically)

Comment: Okay, `cabal repl` worked after `cabal configure`. It respects all the settings in my `.cabal` file too, so that's awesome. Should I always prefer it over just using `ghci` and a `.ghci` file in the project root? Edit: ah, I get it. Thanks!

Comment: yes you should prefer it if you are using sandboxes :D